# Simple Scanner fails to find wifi MG3222 all in one scanner, Printer works

Tags: wireless, printing, canon, scanner

I'm trying to get the Simple Scanner to connect to wifi MG3222, the printer connects good and prints a test page and any other doc. The desk top is running Ubuntu 14.04 up to date software, 32bit computer. I have performed the terminal commands indicated on the fixes here and even did them all again using the software installer and synaptic software installer so have the install cnijfilter-common scangearmp-common also cnijfilter-mg3200 and scangearmp-mg3200 and still can't get the simple scanner to see the all in one wifi printer scanner. I also did sudo apt-get update etc. 
I wish the simple scan window would have a tab to search the network for the scanner or even allow ip address of the printer to be entered so it know where to look.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer that works, thanks Phil

Answer (score 0):

Canon has their own scanning software *ScanGear* - I know that there is a version available for the MG2920, but you may have to wait until they produce a version for the MG3222.

You could also examine the source code, or the driver for the MG2920, and see if they will work for your printer.  The page with links to the source code and drivers is [here](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/inkjet-multifunction/mg-series-inkjet/mg2920?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25)